# Can't install unity-tweak-tool from Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: unity, apt, package-management, synaptic

When I click on it and select `Mark for Installation` a list of packages `to be installed` is shown which are the following:

```
libhardware2
libhybris
libhybris-common1
libmedia1
libqt.5position5
oxideqt-codecs
qml-module-qt-labs-settings
qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
```

I press `Mark` then I press `Apply`. I get an error saying `Could not apply changes! Fix broken packages first.` Then I go to the list of `Broken` packages and `unity-tweak-tool` is there. And when I run `Fix Broken Packages` I get error saying I have held packages but when I run `apt-mark showhold`  it doesn't show anything.

I've installed `unity-tweak-tool` before and did some changes. And the changes are still here. As I remember, I pressed reset and the UI broke down (I installed a theme using unity-tweak-tool).

I also tried running `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove unity-tweak-tool` but it says that it is not installed.

EDIT: What I mean with the changes are still here is the `Horizontal Fold effect on Maximize` not sure if that is the default or what but any other changes I did using unity-tweak-tool is gone. The themes and stuff.

EDIT 2: This is my very first time trying out Ubuntu (also my very first Linux experience).

EDIT 3: The feature `Minimize on click` is also still here which I think can only be enabled from `unity-tweak-tool`.

EDIT 4: There's also this red exclamation mark beside the package name after I select `Mark for Installation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have broken packages. And the changes applied via tweak tool will remain even if the tool is removed. Also the unity tweak tool has been removed from the system during the update or during installing another package.

You can do couple of things.

1) Run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

see if that fixes.

If it does not,

2) Did you install any updates recently or any new software using some ppa? Then remove that ppa or any other unwanted ppas using

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:yourppaname/here
```

3) Then run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: I didn't use `ppa-purge` because I don't know what to put after it so I just removed the repositories from `Software and Updates`. `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` was not enough. I used `sudo aptitude install unity-tweak-tool` and it offered some solutions to install missing dependencies and so I did. Nonetheless, your answer helped me.

Comment: You did a mistake. Doing ppa-purge will not only remove ppas but also downgrade dependencies, remove unnecessary packages and does a lot more. See here to see what I am talking about: http://askubuntu.com/questions/862706/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-this-specific-situation/862775#862775  I faced the same issue and ppa-purge saved me.

Comment: I used `apt-cache policy` command ot list all ppa repositories and from there I don't know what snippet to put in `ppa:no-idea-what-to-put-here` that's why I used the `Software and Updates > Other Software`. Nevertheless `unity-tweak-tool` is already working. And I've also noticed that installing `gnome-tweak-tool` will replace it.